# Remove Brackets and Single quotes from list loaded from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, csvreader

I am opening a .csv file that contains links and I want to navigate to each one.  But when i print the list of links, it has brackets and single quotes around them.  How do I print the links without the brackets and single quotes?

```
import csv
import os

with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  links = list(reader)

for i in links:
    print(i)
```

Results

```
['https://links.com/100GLC-PFAQ-6X9?idc=43']
['https://links.com/100GLC-PFAQ-9X12?idc=43']
['https://links.com/100LB-PFLIN-9X12?idc=43']
['https://links.com/14PT-PFUV-5.25X10.5?idc=43']
['https://links.com/14PT-PFUV-6X9?idc=43']
['https://links.com/14PT-PFUV-9X12?idc=43']
```

**UPDATE**
I solved the issue using the *.  Below is my updated code.

```
import csv
import os

with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  links = list(reader)

for i in links:
    print(*i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the *. Below is my updated code.

```
import csv
import os

with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  links = list(reader)

for i in links:
    print(*i)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do next:

```
import csv
import os

links = []

with open('links.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  links.extend(reader)

print(links) # show all links without for loop
```